# Accesing XML elements using groovy

Tags: groovy, xml-parsing

I need to parse xml file depending on command line arguments passed. There are only two parameters which are passed to the groovy program. I am able to parse and get the result when both the parameters are passed, but could not get the program working when the optional parameter (second parameter) is not passed.

```
<env> 
    <environment name="qa">
        <server name="qaserver1">
            <vip>12.13.14.15</vip>
            <vip>12.13.14.16</vip>
        </server>
        <server name="qaserver2">
            <vip>12.13.14.17</vip>
            <vip>12.13.14.18</vip>
        </server>
    </environment>
</env>
```

Need this code block to work when serverName is not passed in the argument

```
// Assuming both parameters are passed, this block works
def envName = "qa"
def serverName = "qaserver1"
def env = new XmlSlurper().parse("vips.xml")
env.environment.find{ environment -> 
    environment.@name == envName
}.server.find { server -> 
    server.@name == serverName
}.vip.each{ 
    println it.text() 
}
```

Comment: what are the parameters?

Comment: what is you code supposed to do, if the value there is missing?  please provide an example

Comment: @Will P envName and serverName are the parameters passed from command line. I have hard coded these in this example.

Comment: In the absence of `envName`, for example, in which `environment` should it look at? Or should it fail?

Comment: envName is mandatory, serverName is optional parameter.

Comment: And in the absence of `serverName`, it must print every server name?

Comment: In absence of serverName, it should print all the vips containing in the environment specified i.e if envName= "qa" I need all vips  12.13.14.15 through 12.13.14.18, if the serverName is passed in then it should print only vips containing in the server.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it. You can use Groovy's builtin `CliBuilder` to parse command line arguments.

I defined the XML in the script but you can keep reading from the file as you are doing.

The main point here is the `def vips` part: there must be a conditional to check whether a `serverName` was provided. If none, then all servers must be obtained from the XML. Note `.vip.flatten()` is executed regardless of the result in `environment.server...`.

```
def cli = new CliBuilder()
cli.envName required: true, "Environment name", args: 1
cli.serverName required: false, "Server name", args: 1
def opt = cli.parse args

if (!opt) return


def xml = '''<env> 
    <environment name="qa">
        <server name="qaserver1">
            <vip>12.13.14.15</vip>
            <vip>12.13.14.16</vip>
        </server>
        <server name="qaserver2">
            <vip>12.13.14.17</vip>
            <vip>12.13.14.18</vip>
        </server>
    </environment>
</env>'''


def envName = opt.envName
def serverName = opt.serverName
def env = new XmlSlurper().parseText xml

environment = env.environment.find { it.@name.text() == envName }

def vips = ((serverName) ? 
  { environment.server.find { it.@name == serverName } } : 
  { environment.server }
)().vip.flatten()

vips.each { println it.text() }
```

Comment: It is interesting that you mark this question as the correct one, which helps people with the same question.